# angularjs convert date format to IST

Tags: angularjs

I want to convert date from **2015-12-02T18:30:00.000+0000** to **Wed Dec 02 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)** using angularjs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make use of angular's `date` filter . The formats are clearly given [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

```
{{'2015-12-02T18:30:00.000+0000' | date:"EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:hh:ss 'GMT'Z '(India Standard Time)'"}}
```

The above code snippet will give you `Thu Dec 03 2015 00:12:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` in the output. that is the time when you calculate from `+0000` to a `+0530`

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Yki3S3MTv8qO1BwqdZVU?p=preview) is a working solution

Answer (score 0):

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0m2wabm6/2/)

**HTML:**

```
<div ng:app ng:controller="Scoper">
    Input: {{v}}  <br />
    Angular: {{v | date:'EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss'}} GMT{{v | date:'+0530' }} (India Standard Time) <br />

</div>
```

**JS**

```
function Scoper($scope) {
    var s = "2015-12-02T18:30:00.000+0000";
    $scope.v = s;
}
```